# Use natural deduction to prove an easy logical statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

How to prove 
$(A \rightarrow ( B\vee C) ) \rightarrow  ((A \rightarrow B) \vee(A \rightarrow C))$ when  $\vee$ means or, using natural deduction?

It is easy to prove the converse , but I didn't success to prove that.

Help me please. 
Thanks.

Comment: (Note that I changed ○ to $\vee$ [\vee].)

Comment: @CarlHeckman thank you.

Comment: You also need to clarify what you mean by "natural deduction"; are you allowed to use rules of inference?

Comment: @CarlHeckman yes I think.

Comment: This can be done easiest by contradiction; proof by contrapositive is also possible.

Comment: You missed a bracket, which I added.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use law of excluded middle to split cases cleverly.
$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$

**Sketch**:

If $A \imp B \lor C$:

$B \lor \neg B$. [Put the proof of LEM for $B$ before this.]

If $B$:

...

$A \imp B$.

$( A \imp B ) \lor ( A \imp C )$.

If $\neg B$:

If $A$:

$B \lor C$.

...

$C$.

$A \imp C$.

$( A \imp B ) \lor ( A \imp C )$.

...

Comment: thanks,but I didn't understand the case which B is false. Explain please.

Comment: @user115608: Do specify which line you cannot figure out how to derive.

Comment: in line 9 where u said $B \vee C $ then how u conclude $C $ ?

Comment: @user115608: From "$\neg B$" and "$B \lor C$" it is a short proof to derive $C$. Can you see how? Hint: If $\neg C$ then ...

Comment: In Polish notation one might write 1. CCpAqrACpqCpr.  2. CCpAqrACpqCsr and 3. CCpAqrACsqCpr have the same bracket type as 1. and are tautologies also.  A double check on that is here: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_BY5vtccr9k_0.py  Neither 2. nor 3. has a converse like 1.  If we assume the disjunction of the first variable and the negation of the first variable instead of that of the second variable, with some more work, all three of those tautologies can proved with a similar plan for each of them.  But, I believe any of those proofs longer than the idea sketched above.

Comment: @user115608: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831/troll-or-skeptic/2867.